# How to set active item in the Action Bar drop-down navigation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

I'm trying to fix the issue with restarting activity on orientation changes.

I have an `ActionBar` with drop-down list navigation and after every rotation first element of this list is being activated. Keeping `fragment` content wasn't difficult, but I don't know how to set active list item.

Here is the definition of `ActionBar`:

```
getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter
    .createFromResource(this, R.array.action_list, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
list.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
```

And here is my workaround:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    if (!application.isRotated) {
        application.activePosition = itemPosition;
        application.activeId = itemId;
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(android.R.id.content, MyFragment.newInstance(itemPosition))
            .commit();
    } else {
        application.isRotated = false;
        this.onNavigationItemSelected(application.activePosition, application.activeId);            
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    application.isRotated = true;
}
```

I'm not sure it's the best solution though.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I just found that function. It is [`setSelectedNavigationItem(int position)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setSelectedNavigationItem%28int%29).

> Set the selected navigation item **in list** or tabbed navigation modes.

Example:

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, this);
actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
```

Comment: Would you mind posting an example of how you got this to work?  I've been trying something like getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(1) but it has no effect.. (Someone else with the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8487425/actionbar-dropdown-spinner-item-defaults-to-first-item)

Comment: Sure, updated my answer. Also, you can take a look at the source code of my app to see how I use it. https://github.com/Tsukanov/Simple-Counter/blob/master/src/me/tsukanov/counter/CounterActivity.java#L90

Comment: Thanks, it works!  I guess what I must have been doing wrong was calling the setSelectedNavigationItem before adding the adapter.  Was sure I tried it that way before but oh well, works now :)

Comment: Sorry about that. [This one](https://github.com/Tsukanov/Simple-Counter/blob/6fa75ccb0bdfb3059f44289eba4517257ecb2012/src/me/tsukanov/counter/ui/CounterActivity.java#L327) should work even after I make any changes.

Answer (score 1):

As of support library v7, you just need to save / restore the state of the ActionBar:

```
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selectedNavItem";

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Restore the previously serialized current dropdown position.
    if (savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM)) {
        getSupportActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(
                savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM));
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Serialize the current dropdown position.
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM, getSupportActionBar()
            .getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing the same issue. Making a lot of research I found the solution here:

http://mohitum.wordpress.com/tutorials/android/       -->under Tip 5.

Implement OnPageChangeListener and in the onPageSelected(int position) call this method like this:

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
  mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
  selectInSpinnerIfPresent(position, true);
}
private void selectInSpinnerIfPresent(int position, boolean animate) {
  try {
    ActionBar actionBarView = mActionBar;
    Class<?> actionBarViewClass = actionBarView.getClass();
    Field mTabScrollViewField = actionBarViewClass.getDeclaredField(“mTabScrollView”);
    mTabScrollViewField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mTabScrollView = mTabScrollViewField.get(actionBarView);
    if (mTabScrollView == null) {
      return;
    }
    Field mTabSpinnerField = mTabScrollView.getClass().getDeclaredField(“mTabSpinner”);
    mTabSpinnerField.setAccessible(true);
    Object mTabSpinner = mTabSpinnerField.get(mTabScrollView);
    if (mTabSpinner == null) {
      return;
    }
    Method setSelectionMethod = mTabSpinner.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod(“setSelection”, Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE);
    setSelectionMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner, position, animate);
    Method requestLayoutMethod = mTabSpinner.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod(“requestLayout”);
    requestLayoutMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

I hope this may help someone else too.

Answer (score 0):

[Codesnippet on Gist](https://gist.github.com/toulouse/2657485)

---

```
@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
}


@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
}


@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

    selectInSpinnerIfPresent(position, true);
}


/**
 * Hack that takes advantage of interface parity between ActionBarSherlock and the native interface to reach inside
 * the classes to manually select the appropriate tab spinner position if the overflow tab spinner is showing.
 * 
 * Related issues: https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/issues/240 and
 * https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/32492/
 * 
 * @author toulouse@crunchyroll.com
 */
private void selectInSpinnerIfPresent(int position, boolean animate) {
    try {
        View actionBarView = findViewById(R.id.abs__action_bar);
        if (actionBarView == null) {
            int id = getResources().getIdentifier("action_bar", "id", "android");
            actionBarView = findViewById(id);
        }

        Class<?> actionBarViewClass = actionBarView.getClass();
        Field mTabScrollViewField = actionBarViewClass.getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
        mTabScrollViewField.setAccessible(true);

        Object mTabScrollView = mTabScrollViewField.get(actionBarView);
        if (mTabScrollView == null) {
            return;
        }

        Field mTabSpinnerField = mTabScrollView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mTabSpinner");
        mTabSpinnerField.setAccessible(true);

        Object mTabSpinner = mTabSpinnerField.get(mTabScrollView);
        if (mTabSpinner == null) {
            return;
        }

        Method setSelectionMethod = mTabSpinner.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("setSelection", Integer.TYPE, Boolean.TYPE);
        setSelectionMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner, position, animate);

        Method requestLayoutMethod = mTabSpinner.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("requestLayout");
        requestLayoutMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

this hack around the official Android Bug did it for me, the codesnippet above did not :/

Answer (score 0):

This implementation works for me (a modified version of @mohitum007's response):

```
public static void selectInSpinnerIfPresent(Object inActionBar,
        int position, boolean animate) {
    // get the ActionBar class
    Class<?> actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();

    // if it is a Jelly Bean implementation (ActionBarImplJB), get the super
    // class (ActionBarImplICS)
    if ("android.support.v7.app.ActionBarImplJB".equals(actionBarClass
            .getName())) {
        actionBarClass = actionBarClass.getSuperclass();
    }
    try {
        // try to get the mActionBar field, because the current ActionBar is
        // probably just a wrapper Class
        // if this fails, no worries, this will be an instance of the native
        // ActionBar class or from the ActionBarImplBase class
        final Field actionBarField = actionBarClass
                .getDeclaredField("mActionBar");
        actionBarField.setAccessible(true);
        inActionBar = actionBarField.get(inActionBar);
        actionBarClass = inActionBar.getClass();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }
    try {
        Field mTabScrollViewField = actionBarClass
                .getDeclaredField("mTabScrollView");
        mTabScrollViewField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mTabScrollView = mTabScrollViewField.get(inActionBar);
        if (mTabScrollView == null) {
            return;
        }
        Field mTabSpinnerField = mTabScrollView.getClass()
                .getDeclaredField("mTabSpinner");
        mTabSpinnerField.setAccessible(true);
        Object mTabSpinner = mTabSpinnerField.get(mTabScrollView);
        if (mTabSpinner == null) {
            return;
        }
        Method setSelectionMethod = mTabSpinner
                .getClass()
                .getSuperclass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("setSelection", Integer.TYPE,
                        Boolean.TYPE);
        setSelectionMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner, position, animate);
        Method requestLayoutMethod = mTabSpinner.getClass().getSuperclass()
                .getDeclaredMethod("requestLayout");
        requestLayoutMethod.invoke(mTabSpinner);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | InvocationTargetException
            | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | NoSuchFieldException e) {
    }
}
```