# Dialog gets closed on screen rotation android

Tags: android

I create a PreferenceActivity which has a ListPreference(prefViewPos) and a Preference(prefAlert). When the user click on the 'prefAlert' a OK Cancel dialog is open. Now when screen is rotated my alert dialog gets closed but if 'prefViewPos' dialog is open then it is not closed. So why my alert dialog gets closed while ListPreference dialog not closed on screen rotation?

**Code:**

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.setting);
getListView().setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
getListView().setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
prefViewPos = (ListPreference)findPreference(NetworkMonitorApp.PREF_VIEW_POS);
if(prefViewPos != null)
{
    String viewPosEntries[] = {"Top Left","Top Center","Top Right"};
    String viewPosEntryValues[] = {String.valueOf(0),String.valueOf(1),String.valueOf(2)};
    prefViewPos.setEntries(viewPosEntries);
    prefViewPos.setEntryValues(viewPosEntryValues); 
    if(prefViewPos != null)
    {
        prefViewPos.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference arg0, Object arg1) 
            {
                //Some code here
                return true;
            }
        }); 
    }
}
prefAlert = (Preference)findPreference("PrefAlert");
if(prefAlert != null)
{
    prefTextColor.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) 
        {
            //Open dialog by AlertDialog.Builder.show()
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your activity code?

Answer (score 2):

This is because your activity is recreated on orientation change. See: [Activity Life-cycle Management](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) [developer.android.com].

**UPDATE:**

The dialog for the list preference is a part of the preference hierarchy and is created by android. Hence it is saved and restored by android in the PreferenceActivity's onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() calls. Whereas you are creating the dialog for your Preference "prefAlert" and must save and restore in your class' onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState methods. See this: [Recreating an activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html) [developer.android.com]

Comment: I know it but why ListPreference not getting closed?

Comment: Might be that preference activity saves and recreates it. I will look into the source code for that. Which platform are you building for (the target sdk in your manifest)?

Comment: android:targetSdkVersion="15"

Answer (score 1):

did u define it in manifest in that activity

```
 android:configChanges="orientation" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `PreferenceFragment` you are probably creating a new fragment on orientation change instead of reusing the old one. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14304020/330779).