# How to change the layout of DialogFragment when the screen is rotated in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, screen-rotation

I have a custom `DialogFragment`, which contains two `DatePicker` widgets (from and to, using layout/custom_date_picker).

[image]

I need change the layout of dialogFragment when the screen is rotated to landscape (using layout-land/custom_date_picker).

[image]

The configuration of the `Activity` is :

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"/>
```

The implemented `DialogFragment` source is:

```
public class DatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment
{

public static final String START_SEARCH_DATE = "startSearchDate";
public static final String END_SEARCH_DATE = "endSearchDate";
private CustomDatePicker dpStartDate;
private CustomDatePicker dpEndDate;
private AlertDialog d;

public interface DatePickerDialogListener
{
    void onFinishDatePickDialog(String fromDate, String toDate);
}

public DatePickerDialog()
{
}

// Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
DatePickerDialogListener mListener;

// Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the DatePickerDialogListener
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
    try
    {
        // Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
        mListener = (DatePickerDialogListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement DatePickerDialogListener");
    }
}

public static DatePickerDialog newInstance(String startSearchDate, String endSearchDate)
{
    DatePickerDialog frag = new DatePickerDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(START_SEARCH_DATE, startSearchDate);
    args.putString(END_SEARCH_DATE, endSearchDate);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View customView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_date_picker, null);
    // Define your date pickers
    dpStartDate = (CustomDatePicker) customView.findViewById(R.id.dpStartDate);
    dpEndDate = (CustomDatePicker) customView.findViewById(R.id.dpEndDate);

    String startSearchDate = getArguments().getString(START_SEARCH_DATE);
    String endSearchDate = getArguments().getString(END_SEARCH_DATE);

    dpStartDate.updateDate(startSearchDate);
    dpEndDate.updateDate(endSearchDate);

    d = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(customView)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.datepicker_hint))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            }) //Set to null. We override the onclick
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), null)
            .create();
    d.show();
    d.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            boolean b = DateUtils.largerThanEndDate(dpStartDate, dpEndDate);
            if (b)
            {
                ToastUtils.showShortText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.date_error));
            } else
            {
                mListener.onFinishDatePickDialog(dpStartDate.getDate(), dpEndDate.getDate());
                dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    return d;
}
}
```

Can anyone please guide me as to how this can be done ? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Here the code with which I invoke the `DialogFragment`:

```
public void showDatePicker()
{
    startSearchDate = dateModel.getStartDate();
    endSearchDate = dateModel.getEndDate();
    datePickerDialog = (DatePickerDialog)fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);

    if (alertDialog == null)
    {
        alertDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(startSearchDate, endSearchDate);
        alertDialog.show(fragmentManager, DATE_PICKER_DIALOG);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Y.S. Now I click the button and show the dialog,but the  layout can't be changed when the screen is rotated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could consider using an `if` clause in your `onCreate()` as follows:

```
int rotation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
```

and then do

```
switch(rotation){
    case Surface.ROTATION_0: 
    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
        // show portrait

    case Surface.ROTATION_90: 
    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
        // show landscape
}
```

For portrait mode, show the two dialogs stacked. And for landscape mode, show them side-by-side.

**EDIT:**

Answering point-wise:

- When the phone is rotated, the `Activity` is necessarily re-created.
  This means that `onCreate()` *will* be called on rotation. Hence, the rotation ***state*** can be determined in `onCreate()` as shown above. In this case, make `rotation` a class member field so that it can be accessed throughout the class.
- Indeed, as you correctly point out, the dialog can be shown from either `onConfigurationChanged()` or in `onCreate()` itself. For this, and for how to save the instance state, please see the attached links.

**References:**

**1.** [How to properly retain a DialogFragment through rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14657490/3287204).

**2.** [Why won't Fragment retain state when screen is rotated?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14184182/3287204).

Comment: I think I should show the dialog in onConfigurationChanged method,but I am not sure how to change the layout of dialog and save the state of datepicker.

Comment: Thanks your info. I have read the references,but can't solve my problem.Please see my edited.How can I change the dialog layout (just invoking the showDatePicker() can't work properly)from onConfigurationChanged method?

Comment: did you manage to solve this? I have the same problem