# Passing data between Fragments and saving state on Screen Orientation Change

Tags: android, fragment, communication, state, screen-orientation

Before I begin, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951730/viewpager-and-fragments-whats-the-right-way-to-store-fragments-state), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983396/fragment-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-called-twice/14295474#14295474) and some more articles online. I am still unable to find a right way to do it.

So I have just **one activity** in my App, and **6 fragments**. First one is a `ListFragment` which loads a list from a SQLite table. When user taps on a row in this list, I do 2 things:

1) Get an **int** from that row through a listener, and pass it back to the parent activity which stores it as a class variable using a simple setter method.
2) Replace this `ListFragment` with another simple `Fragment`. This new Fragment uses a simple **getter()** on that class variable to retrieve some information from a different table, and show all the details to the user.

So far so good. Now if I am on this details Fragment, and I change the screen orientation, the activity state is not reloaded (as I am checking if `savedInstanceState` is **null** in the `onCreate()`), but however, the class variables lose their value, and my app crashes.

Basically I am trying to pass data from the ListFragment to the details Fragment. I am doing it through the activity, which is causing a problem. As per Android Documentation:

> All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated
>   Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

There is no specific code which is giving me trouble, so didn't post any.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState` is only used to save and restore per-instance state of an activity in case your activity is destroyed by OS (for example, to free the memory or in order to recreate it when the device orientation was changed). So you can save your variable in `onSaveInstanceState` and get them back using `onRestoreInstanceState`.

For your next question, I think this [article](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) will help you. Also answer by Gene for this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5194548/how-to-pass-data-between-fragments) will help you.