# fragment onCreateView called many times

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I'm attaching the fragment (many fragments to `FrameLayout`) of an `Activity` each fragment has its own view inflated in `onCreateView()`.

Now,

If I rotate the screen Landscape/Protrait the `onCreateView()` of the fragment is called instead of calling its attached Activity's `onCreate()` method. Because of this the view are rendered twice.

I want the Activity's `onCreate()` to be called every time when there is a config changes. Is it possible?

**Activity :** *MainActivity.java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.layout_replace, new MyFragment()).commit();
}
```

**Fragment :** *MyFragment.java*

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {         
    return (ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: When you rotate, the `Activity` is destroyed and started. if a `Fragment` is attached, `onCreateView()` will be called. Could you show a part of your code ?

Comment: @FlorianMacLanglade I have updated my sample code

Comment: Do you need to have the fragment added dynamically? If not, you can declare the fragment directly in your layout xml.

Comment: ya it has to added dynamically

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Fixed this!!

Actual problem was with `FragmentTransaction` for which I'm adding fragments using [`.add()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#add%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29) which causes the view to be populated twice.

**Instead use :**

[`.replace(R.id.yourId, fragment)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment%29)

Comment: Wow. Saved me a lot of time. Thanks @yashhy.