# android fragment savedInstanceState value being reset when screen rotates

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I'm am working on a project and am running into a bug that I can not seem to figure why it is happening. The problem is that I want to save the value of score when I flip the orientation of my phone. when I log the value of score I notice the problem, which is that the `onCreateView` seems to be called twice when I change my phone's orientation. In the log during the first call it seems to save the value of score, but than it gets called again clearing the value of score.

- Why is the `onCreateView` getting called twice and reseting the value of score?
- How do I fix it so that `onCreateView` is called only once?

  ```
  public class SteeringFragment extends Fragment {



  Drawable transparentRadioButton;
  RadioButton rbExcellent, rbGood, rbFair, rbPoor, rbFailing;
  LinearLayout llExcellent, llGood, llFair, llPoor, llFailing;

  int score;



  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.steering_title);


      // Inflate the layout for this fragment
      View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_steering, container, false);

      if (savedInstanceState != null){
          score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score");
      }



      Log.d("test", String.valueOf(score));


      llExcellent = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringLLExcellent);
      llGood = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringLLGood);
      llFair = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringLLFair);
      llPoor = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringLLPoor);
      llFailing = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringLLFailing);

      rbExcellent = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringRadioExcellent);
      rbGood = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringRadioGood);
      rbFair =  (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringRadioFair);
      rbPoor = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringRadioPoor);
      rbFailing = (RadioButton)view.findViewById(R.id.steeringRadioFailing);


      //used to hide the radio button
      transparentRadioButton = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
      rbExcellent.setButtonDrawable(transparentRadioButton);
      rbGood.setButtonDrawable(transparentRadioButton);
      rbFair.setButtonDrawable(transparentRadioButton);
      rbPoor.setButtonDrawable(transparentRadioButton);
      rbFailing.setButtonDrawable(transparentRadioButton);


      //if score already has value set it to the value
      if (score != 0){
          switch (score){
              case 5:
                  rbExcellent.setChecked(true);
                  rbGood.setChecked(false);
                  rbFair.setChecked(false);
                  rbPoor.setChecked(false);
                  rbFailing.setChecked(false);
                  rbExcellent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.excellentColor));
                  llExcellent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  break;
              case 4:
                  rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
                  rbGood.setChecked(true);
                  rbFair.setChecked(false);
                  rbPoor.setChecked(false);
                  rbFailing.setChecked(false);
                  rbGood.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.goodColor));
                  llGood.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  break;
              case 3:
                  rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
                  rbGood.setChecked(false);
                  rbFair.setChecked(true);
                  rbPoor.setChecked(false);
                  rbFailing.setChecked(false);
                  rbFair.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fairColor));
                  llFair.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  break;
              case 2:
                  rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
                  rbGood.setChecked(false);
                  rbFair.setChecked(false);
                  rbPoor.setChecked(true);
                  rbFailing.setChecked(false);
                  rbPoor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.poorColor));
                  llPoor.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  break;
              case 1:
                  rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
                  rbGood.setChecked(false);
                  rbFair.setChecked(false);
                  rbPoor.setChecked(false);
                  rbFailing.setChecked(true);
                  rbFailing.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.failingColor));
                  llFailing.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  break;
          }
      }


      rbExcellent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              rbExcellent.setChecked(true);
              rbGood.setChecked(false);
              rbFair.setChecked(false);
              rbPoor.setChecked(false);
              rbFailing.setChecked(false);

          }
      });

      rbGood.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
              rbGood.setChecked(true);
              rbFair.setChecked(false);
              rbPoor.setChecked(false);
              rbFailing.setChecked(false);
          }
      });

      rbFair.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
              rbGood.setChecked(false);
              rbFair.setChecked(true);
              rbPoor.setChecked(false);
              rbFailing.setChecked(false);
          }
      });

      rbPoor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
              rbGood.setChecked(false);
              rbFair.setChecked(false);
              rbPoor.setChecked(true);
              rbFailing.setChecked(false);
          }
      });

      rbFailing.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              rbExcellent.setChecked(false);
              rbGood.setChecked(false);
              rbFair.setChecked(false);
              rbPoor.setChecked(false);
              rbFailing.setChecked(true);
          }
      });

      rbExcellent.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked){

                  rbExcellent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.excellentColor));
                  llExcellent.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  score = 5;


              }else {
                  rbExcellent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.textColor));
                  llExcellent.setBackground(null);
                  llExcellent.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

              }
          }
      });

      rbGood.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked){
                  rbGood.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.goodColor));
                  llGood.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  score = 4;

              }else {
                  rbGood.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.textColor));
                  llGood.setBackground(null);
                  llGood.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
              }
          }
      });

      rbFair.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked){
                  rbFair.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.fairColor));
                  llFair.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  score = 3;

              }else {
                  rbFair.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.textColor));
                  llFair.setBackground(null);
                  llFair.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
              }
          }
      });

      rbPoor.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked){
                  rbPoor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.poorColor));
                  llPoor.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  score = 2;

              }else {
                  rbPoor.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.textColor));
                  llPoor.setBackground(null);
                  llPoor.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
              }
          }
      });

      rbFailing.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
          @Override
          public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
              if (isChecked){
                  rbFailing.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.failingColor));
                  llFailing.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.radio_boxes_borders));
                  score = 1;
              }else {
                  rbFailing.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.textColor));
                  llFailing.setBackground(null);
                  llFailing.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
              }
          }
      });





      return view;
  }


  @Override
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
      super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

      outState.putInt("score", score);
  }
  ```

  }

Comment: Hi, please read http://stackoverflow.com/a/10996647/5241603. It may help.

Comment: I saw that and now I understand why it is happening, but I don't understand his explanation on how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

In your fragment code try to store these lines:

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
    score = savedInstanceState.getInt("score");
}
```

in your fragment's `onCreate` method, Every time that you rotate your device `onCreateView` is called (because the UI is re drawed) and some of their parameters will be cleaned.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work either, the problem is still happening.

Comment: You could try use breakpoints to see what happens to savedInstanceState value when you rotate the devide.