# Fragment's onCreateView(), onActivityCreated() recalled while navigating back using navigation component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying to implement a navigation component into the Android app and noticed one issue while navigating back from one fragment to another fragment.

Currently, I have 3 fragments (A,B and C) inside one activity whenever I click the back button from fragment B or C the previous fragment onCreateView(), and onActivityCreated() is recalled hence the user selection and other details get refreshed. I am using following version of the navigation component.

```
ext.nav_version = '2.6.0'
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
```

Comment: The Lifecycle of a View is not inherently tied to the lifecycle of a Fragment. When you move from one Fragment to another, its view gets destroyed because there is no reason for keeping it in memory. This is intended behavior - I think your problem might be in what you are doing in onCreateView.

Comment: @TheLibrarian I am not doing anything in onCreateView method but it's also recalling onActivityCreated() hence that is the concern.

Comment: Oh right - I "read between the lines" that one - I think those questions might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10983396/fragment-oncreateview-and-onactivitycreated-called-twice and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474104/android-fragment-lifecycle-over-orientation-changes/8678705#8678705

Comment: @TheLibrarian Without a navigation component if we go with a simple fragment transaction API it works fine there is no doubt about that. I am exploring the new Navigation Component hence raising the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment#onActivityCreated` has been `deprecated` - mainly because of what you are describing - it gets called multiple times even though the underlying `Activity`s `onCreate` has been called only once - [Bug issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144309266).

**TL;DR** is - if you were doing anything related to `View`s in `onActivityCreated`, do it in `onViewCreated`.

The other logic that could have been handled is recommended to either move to onCreate or attach lifecycle observer for `CREATED`