# Android activity lifecycle - same method gets called twice

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a method that gets called both from `onNavigationItemSelected` of `ActionBar` and `onResume` lifecycle methods. So, when the `Activity` gets created, the method gets called twice.

So will it be possible to implement like that when the method is called from `onNavigationItemSelected`, it should not get called from `onResume`?

Comment: How about Adding it only in OnResume ??

Comment: Put the method reference only in onCreate

Comment: so the method is called from 3 places ? onNavigationItemSelected , onresume and oncreate ?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517749/android-action-bar-onnavigationitemselected

Comment: No, it is called from `onResume` and `onNavigationItemSelected` only. It is not called from `onCreate`.

Comment: Tried ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517749/android-action-bar-onnavigationitemselected

Comment: Yes, that comes closest to a solution. Could you please post this as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a manual flag/boolean  as used here [android action bar onNavigationItemSelected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517749/android-action-bar-onnavigationitemselected)

so that you can ignore the first call to onNavigationItemSelected method

Answer (score 1):

Only call your method in `onResume`. 
`onResume` is called when the Activity is created the first time as well.
See [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for further details.

Comment: Sorry, I had to rephrase the question. Please see that.

Answer (score 0):

In Activity life cycle OnCreate() is called only once and OnResume() is called every time after stop, pause, start and before OnCreate. So decide what you actually want. If you want to call method on every resume then call it only in OnResume not in OnCreate..