# Infinite loop when using onNavigationItemSelected and invalidateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, infinite-loop, android-menu

I have an action bar which contains a list navigation and a sub menu. I want to update the sub menu items according to the user selection in the list navigation. I'm trying to call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` in the `onNavigationItemSelected()` but this creates an infinite loop.

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    invalidateOptionsMenu();
    Log.i("onNavigationItemSelected", "onNavigationItemSelected called");
    return true;
}
```

I'm using `ActionBarSherlock`. This is one of my first Android/Java project.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517749/android-action-bar-onnavigationitemselected You probably set a different index in the invalidateOptionsMenu().