# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException at VideoListFragment

Tags: android, stack-trace, indexoutofboundsexception

I am getting a runtime exception:

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=4   at
>   com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment.onCreateView(VideoListFragment.java:110)

I mentioned that line no.110 in below coding.

**StackTrace:**

```
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): Process: com.loco.android, PID: 2402
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=4
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment.onCreateView(VideoListFragment.java:110)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-25 04:55:10.808: E/AndroidRuntime(2402):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**VideoListFragment.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.frgment;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class VideoListFragment extends Fragment {

    OnVideoSelectedListener mCallback;
    boolean loadingMore = false;

    // create string variables
    String YOUTUBE_USERNAME = "";

    private String YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
            "&v=2"+
            "&start-index=1"+
            "&max-results=10";

    // create object of views
    ListView list;
    ProgressBar prgLoading;
    Button btnRefresh;
    Button btnLoadMore;

    // create variable to get position, connection status, resources, and channel username
    int position;
    boolean isConnect = true;
    Resources res;
    String[] ChannelUsername;

    // create object of custom adapter
    VideoListAdapter vla;

    // create arraylist variables
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // flag for current page
    int current_page = 1;
    int previous_page;

    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_THUMBNAIL = "thumbnail";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

    // create interface listener
    public interface OnVideoSelectedListener{
        public void onVideoSelected(String ID);
    }

     @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

            list = (ListView)view .findViewById(R.id.list);
            btnRefresh = (Button)view .findViewById(R.id.btnRefresh);

        menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // get value that passed from previous page
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        position = bundle.getInt("position", 0);

        // get channel username and put selected channel to youtube api
        res = getActivity().getResources();
        ChannelUsername = res.getStringArray(R.array.channel_username);
        YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];---->Error at Line 110

        YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
                "&v=2"+
                "&start-index=1"+
                "&max-results=10";

        // create LoadMore button
        btnLoadMore = new Button(getActivity());
        btnLoadMore.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_default_holo_light);
        btnLoadMore.setText(getString(R.string.load_more));

        // adding load more button to lisview at bottom
        list.addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

        new loadFirstListView().execute();

        // listener to handle load more buttton when clicked
        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Starting a new async task
                isConnect = true;
                new loadMoreListView().execute();
            }
        });



        // listener to handle list when clicked
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
                item = menuItems.get(position);

                mCallback.onVideoSelected(item.get("id"));

                list.setItemChecked(position, true);
            }
        });

        // listener to handle refresh button when clicked
        btnRefresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                isConnect = true;
                new loadFirstListView().execute();
            }
        });
        return view;        
    }


@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
        // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception.
        try {
            mCallback = (OnVideoSelectedListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
        }
    }


    // load first 10 videos
    private class loadFirstListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);

                // Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(YOUTUBE_API);
                // Get the response that YouTube sends back
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                // Convert this response into an inputstream for the parser to use
                InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }


                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONObject dataObject = json.getJSONObject("data"); // this is the "data": { } part
                    JSONArray items = dataObject.getJSONArray("items"); // this is the "items: [ ] part


                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject youtubeObject = items.getJSONObject(i); 

                        map.put(KEY_ID, youtubeObject.getString("id")); // id not using any where
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, youtubeObject.getString("title"));
                        map.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL, youtubeObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("hqDefault"));

                        String duration = secondToTime(youtubeObject.getInt("duration"));
                        map.put(KEY_DURATION, duration);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                isConnect = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }   

            return (null);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(isAdded()){
                if(isConnect){
                    btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    // Getting adapter
                    vla = new VideoListAdapter(getActivity(), menuItems);
                    list.setAdapter(vla);

                }else{
                    btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // load more videos
    private class loadMoreListView extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(
                    getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {

            // store previous value of current page
            previous_page = current_page;
            // increment current page
                    current_page += 10;

                    YOUTUBE_API = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/"+YOUTUBE_USERNAME+"/uploads?alt=jsonc" +
                    "&v=2"+
                    "&start-index="+current_page+
                    "&max-results=10";

            try {

                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), 15000);

                // Perform a GET request to YouTube for a JSON list of all the videos by a specific user
                HttpUriRequest request = new HttpGet(YOUTUBE_API);
                // Get the response that YouTube sends back
                HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
                // Convert this response into an inputstream for the parser to use
                InputStream atomInputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();


                 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(atomInputStream));

                //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(tc.getInputStream()));
                String line;
                String str = "";
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null){
                    str += line;
                }


                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(str);
                    JSONObject dataObject = json.getJSONObject("data"); // this is the "data": { } part
                    JSONArray items = dataObject.getJSONArray("items"); // this is the "items: [ ] part


                    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {

                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        JSONObject youtubeObject = items.getJSONObject(i); 

                        map.put(KEY_ID, youtubeObject.getString("id")); // id not using any where
                        map.put(KEY_TITLE, youtubeObject.getString("title"));
                        map.put(KEY_THUMBNAIL, youtubeObject.getJSONObject("thumbnail").getString("hqDefault"));

                        String duration = secondToTime(youtubeObject.getInt("duration"));
                        map.put(KEY_DURATION, duration);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        menuItems.add(map);
                    }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                isConnect = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }   



            return (null);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();

            if(isConnect){
                // get listview current position - used to maintain scroll position
                int currentPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();


                btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Appending new data to menuItems ArrayList
                vla = new VideoListAdapter(
                        getActivity(),
                        menuItems);
                list.setAdapter(vla);
                // Setting new scroll position
                list.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 0);

            }else{
                if(menuItems != null){
                    current_page = previous_page;
                    btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    btnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.no_connection), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    // method to convert second to hours, minutes, and seconds
    String secondToTime(int duration){

        String time = "";

        String Hours = "";
        String Minutes = "";
        String Seconds = "";

        double hours = 0.0;
        double minutes = 0.0;
        double seconds = 0.0;

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");

        hours = duration / 3600;
        minutes = (duration % 3600) /60;
        seconds = duration % 60;

        if((hours < 10) && (hours > 0)){
            Hours = "0" + df.format(hours);
        }else if(hours == 0){
            Hours = "00";
        }else{
            Hours = df.format(hours);
        }

        if((minutes < 10) && (minutes > 0)){
            Minutes = "0" + df.format(minutes);
        }else if(minutes == 0){
            Minutes = "00";
        }else{
            Minutes = df.format(minutes);
        }

        if((seconds < 10) && (seconds > 0)){
            Seconds = "0" + df.format(seconds);
        }else if(seconds == 0){
            Seconds = "00";
        }else{
            Seconds = df.format(seconds);
        }

        time = Hours +":"+Minutes+":"+Seconds;
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        vla.imageLoader.clearCache();
        Log.d("clear cache", "clear cache");

    }
}
```

**strings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">Loco</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string-array name="channel_name">
        <item >The Loco</item>

    </string-array>
    <string-array name="channel_username">
        <item >LOCOMEDIATVM</item>

    </string-array>
</resources>
```

**EDITED:**

**HomeActivity.java:**

```
package com.sit.loco.activity;

import com.loco.android.R;
import com.sit.loco.frgment.VideoListFragment;

public class HomeActivity extends FragmentActivity 
implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener, VideoListFragment.OnVideoSelectedListener{

// create object of ActionBar and VideoListFragment
ActionBar actionbar;
VideoListFragment videoListFrag;
int selectedItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // add channel list array to actionbar spinner
    Context context = getSupportActionBar().getThemedContext();
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> list = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(context, R.array.channel_name, R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item);
    list.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // remove actionbar title and add spinner to actionbar
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    getActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
    getActionBar().setListNavigationCallbacks(list, this);
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    selectedItem = itemPosition;

    // create object of VideoListFragment and send data position to that fragment
    videoListFrag = new VideoListFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("position", itemPosition);
    videoListFrag.setArguments(bundle);

    // call video list fragment with new data
    getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.content_frame, videoListFrag, "VIDEO_LIST_FRAGMENT")
    .commit();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onVideoSelected(String ID) {

    // call player page to play selected video
    Intent i = new Intent(this, PlayerActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("id", ID);
    startActivity(i);

}
}
```

I didn't know how to solve this.Anybody can help me with this.Thank you.

Comment: why are you passing 4 as position if your array contains just 1 item?

Comment: @blackbelt I didn't know why I got this error.Can you tell me exactly where the error would be occurred

Comment: I don't know exactly where, but probably, before you replace/add your fragment you are settings a bundle as argument for the instance that contains 4 as value for position

Comment: can you please shown setArguments() code ?

Comment: I am edited the post @blackbelt

Comment: how many item in navigation ?

Comment: it looks good. Can you try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: @Haresh I just need to show the list of videos related to a url with the help channel user name.I need to show only one channel user name.

Comment: @blackbelt yes clean and rebuild but it shows the similar error again

Comment: is onNavigationItemSelected called with the correct position? (`0` I would expect)

Comment: if you have only one channel user name then how you get 4 index ?

Comment: Most of the time we faces the indexout of bound exception because of the loop when we executes the loop more the the size of our datastructure for example if we have 6 element in our arraylist or string array or any structure and we are trying to access the 8 element of that so it will return this exception that is well known as Array Index Out of bound exception

Comment: yes I know about it.I run the you tube demo seperately it works fine.But I am trying to adapt in main project that time I got an error. @Hasnain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In VideoListFragment.java:**

I changed this

> YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];---->Error at Line 110

to

> YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[0];

Why I set this position to 0 means I had a only one channel user_name.

Answer (score 1):

Your previous page passes a wrong position:

```
Bundle bundle = getArguments();
position = bundle.getInt("position", 0);
```

Although you could just add a check

```
ChannelUsername = res.getStringArray(R.array.channel_username);
if (position > ChannelUsername.length()-1) {
    YOUTUBE_USERNAME = ChannelUsername[position];
}
```

You'd better figure out why you are sending a wrong position in the first place.

Comment: `08-25 05:24:17.328: V/position(2514): 4                                          
08-25 05:24:18.148: V/test page(2514): here` I got it like that in logcat.

Comment: @Naruto It's obvious that the argument you get is wrong. The problem is not in the code you've shown, rather the activity that sends you this information.

Comment: @Naruto [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9696739/3249477) suggests that you need to intercept first navigation menu item selection as it's done by the system. Perhaps that's your problem as the code seems to be fine.